# In Java Invoking a method using Reflection is not able to find method, when method has baseclass as parameter

Tags: java, reflection

Below is the code snippet, I am trying to invoke the `usingClass` method using REFLECTION. Calling the `usingClass()` method directly(w/o reflection) works when I pass an object of type Child, though when I try to achieve the same thing using Reflection it throws `NoSuchMethodFoundException`. Would like to understand if I am missing something or is there any logic behind this? Please help

```
package Reflection;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestMethodInvocation {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMethodInvocation test = new TestMethodInvocation();
        Child child = new Child();
        Parent parent = (Parent)child;
        Class<? extends Parent> argClassType = parent.getClass();
        Class<? extends TestMethodInvocation>  thisClassType = test.getClass();

        test.usingClass(child);

        Method methodToCall;
        try {
            methodToCall = thisClassType.getDeclaredMethod("usingClass", argClassType);
            methodToCall.invoke(test, parent);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void usingClass(Parent p){
        System.out.println("UsingClass: " + p.getClass());
    }


}
```

**Output is as below.**

```
UsingClass: class Reflection.Child
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Reflection.TestMethodInvocation.usingClass(Reflection.Child)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at Reflection.TestMethodInvocation.main(TestMethodInvocation.java:20)
```

Comment: When posting code samples, please consider doing things like removing auto-generated comments, and rolling up exception handling when it's not directly related to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code does not work is that `getClass()` is dynamically bound. Casting to Parent does not affect the runtime type of your object and so the variables `child` and `parent` contain the same class object.
Unless you explicitly query your instance for its parent class via `getGenericSuperclass()` or something similar, you will have to use the static way mentioned by dystroy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
methodToCall = thisClassType.getDeclaredMethod("usingClass", Parent.class);
```

because the precise exact class of `parent` (which is Child), is used at runtime and the type of the variable holding it changes nothing.

Another (too heavy) way to solve it would be :

```
Class<? extends Parent> argClassType2 = (new Parent()).getClass();
...
    methodToCall = thisClassType.getDeclaredMethod("usingClass", argClassType2);
```

Comment: This fix the problem for the wrong reason. Generics are erased at runtime, so there is no actual difference at runtime between Class<? extends Parent> and Class<Parent>. See Jochen response for the right reason.

Comment: Child Class extends Parent Class as shown below



package Reflection;

public class Parent {
 public Parent(){};
}

-----------------------------------------

package Reflection;

public class Child extends Parent{
 public Child(){
  super();
 }
}

Comment: @Pablo : you're right. I've edited my answer (and upvoted Jochen ;) ).

Comment: thanks Pablo, I know I can easily pass find the method if I pass any argument of type Parent class, but I want the method to be taking base class type of arguemnt, so that I can choose to pass any object to it which extends Parent class. This is not at all weird in Java. The only matter is I am  not facing issue if I am doing it using Reflection. Question is why and what is the resolution.

Comment: Using a Class instance, you may call `getSuperclass()`. I'm not sure I see the real problem. In practice when I have to dynamically load classes to execute methods, I use interfaces instead of looking for methods. Interfaces are cheap (even if they're more expensive than in other languages).